# Does the order of where conditions in hive queries has impact on the query performance?

Tags: performance, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have the problem that my hive SQL queries sometimes result in an full-table scan and last very long. Thus I was wondering whether the order of the where statements really has an impact on the performance of queries.

E.g. the the query has a primary key build on date and secondary key differentiating objects. I'd like to only analyze yesterdays data, which should be much faster than an full table scan.

Query 1:

```
SELECT 
    primarykey, 
    COALESCE(SUM(param1),0L), 
    COALESCE(SUM(param2),0L), 
    param3 
FROM 
    Table 
WHERE
    param1 = "abc" AND
    param2 > 0 AND
    primarykey = yesterdaysdate
GROUP BY 
    param3;
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT 
    primarykey, 
    COALESCE(SUM(param1),0L), 
    COALESCE(SUM(param2),0L), 
    param3 
FROM 
    Table 
WHERE
    primarykey = yesterdaysdate AND
    param1 = "abc" AND
    param2 > 0
GROUP BY 
    param3;
```

Is it possible that query 2 is faster than query 1?

In my opinion this should not have any impact in reason of the query optimizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hive queries internally execute as MR job. The where clause of the query should be treated as filtering criteria. So it should not have any impact over the performance.

Comment: But filtering the map reduce in the wrong order does have an impact!? However using hive I am not building the map reduce statements myself

Comment: @Manuel I think all the filter criteria will be considered at once in a single map reduce task. It should not be like running different or more number of MR jobs for more number of filter criteria.